# How to get launcher in this Ubuntu with xfce?

Tags: 14.04, 18.04, xubuntu, xfce, vnc

I was setting up VNC for my digital ocean droplet (ubuntu 18.04). I followed https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-18-04#step-4-%E2%80%94-running-vnc-as-a-system-service and got it running. However how do I get like the launcher at the bottom of like this image https://assets.digitalocean.com/articles/vnc_1804/vi0hGFq.png in the article?

Comment: What OS/release are you using?  You've tagged two rather different releases, so why?  How does 14.04 relate to your question?

Comment: The dock looks like it could be docky or plank

Comment: This dock is a big XFCE panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This dock is a big XFCE panel. You can manually create one, set its size, and add Launchers to it.

Instead, you can use a dedicated dock like `docky`.
Open a Terminal and enter the following command.

```
sudo apt install docky
```